# Выбрать в автоматическом режиме элемент из ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

Есть таблица `DataGrid`: две колонки, в одной `DataGridTextColumn`, вторая DataGridComboBoxolumn. В `ComboBox` три элемента:

```
кошка, 
пёс,
медведь
```

Если записываешь в `DataGridTextColumn` текст содержания **"Бурый"**, то в `ComboBox` должно высвечиваться **"Медведь"**, если **"Черный"**, то **"Пёс"**, ну и соответственно **"Серая"**, то **"Кошка"**.Анимацию с приблизительным примером и код прилагаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Window x:Class="ComboBox.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboBox"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.Resources>
    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="AnimalsEnum" MethodName="GetValues"
                        ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type Type="local:SecondName"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="DGR" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="FirstName" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="150"/>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="SecondName" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding SecondName}"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AnimalsEnum}}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

```
class Animals
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public SecondName SecondName { get; set; }
}
public enum SecondName
{
    Кошка,
    Пёс,
    Медведь
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<Animals> animals = new ObservableCollection<Animals>();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DGR.ItemsSource = animals;
    }
}
```

Comment: А у вас паттерн MVVM? Просто понять не могу. И решение вам нужно в соответствии данному паттерну или нет?

Comment: Да именно так и надо паттерн MVVM, другой более простой случай у меня получился.

Comment: А в проекте где получилось вы не использовали MVVM? Все писали в code behind?

Comment: Извините, я немного слукавил, в том случае отсутствовала таблица, было: TextBox и ComboBox и через  MainWindow, проделал

Comment: ок, сейчас постараюсь написать ответ

Comment: `DGR.ItemsSource = animals;` - уже является нарушением MVVM подхода!.

Comment: Без комментариев, со временем пойму, созданное мною нарушение.

Comment: Ну так наверно лучше с самого начала пытаться правильно писать, а не тяп ляп. Основная суть MVVM подхода в разделении всего на слои (Model/ViewModel/View), где слои по сути не связаны не как друг с другом. Model не должна знать о View и ViewModel, ViewModel не должен знать о View (его контроллах, свойствах итд), а View не как не должна знать нечего о VM и M слоях. Вот теперь попробуйте убрать в XAML этот кусочек: `x:Name="DGR"` и попробуйте запустить приложение, запустится?

Comment: Ну а в чем проблема? Это бизнес-логика, поэтому она должна содержаться в vm, пишите в сеттере `FirstName` что-то вроде `if (FirstName == "Бурый") SecondName = SecondName.Медведь;`

Comment: Спасибо Вам !!!!

Comment: Прошу прощения, но не могу я с этой проблемой справиться, сотни вариантов попробовал, нет результата, сделал все как надо и MVVM переделал, все к одному сходится - не могу связать DataGridComboBoxColumn c DataGridTextColumn.

Comment: Вам не надо связывать колонки. Работайте с источником данных! У вас должна быть коллекция (в вашем случае `ObservableCollection<Animals>`), она привязывается в `DataGrid`. Каждая колонка в View - это публичное свойство из `Animals`. Вам лишь достаточно при изменении одного свойства, сделать изменение другого, к примеру в `Set` свойства `FirstName` добавить логику как вам показали выше. Не забывайте про INPC для оповещения об изменений.

Comment: public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (Name == "Бурый")
                    Animals = Animals.Медведь;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        } Подскажите пожалуйста данная запись правильная?

Comment: Вы забыли в сеттере написать `name = value;` перед `if`

Comment: Ну ёлки иголки, спасибо Вам, а я уже думал с ума сойду, весь инет перекопал, чего только в голову не лезло.

Comment: Если пишете комментарий, обращайтесь через `@`, иначе я не получу уведомление и не узнаю о комментарии, пока сам не зайду в топик

Comment: @Я не знал этого.

Comment: @Евгений <= вот так, а не просто `@` :)